# Android: Event ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED and ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED not sent to my BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android

Somehow my ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED and ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED was never triggered when I plug/unplug my nexus 6 from charger.

Manifest.xml:

```
    <application
    android:name="com.xxx.xxx.xxx"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

    <receiver android:name=".PowerReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

PowerReceiver.java

```
public class PowerReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "PowerReceiver fired", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

After 3 hours of digging the problem was finally fixed by simply reboot my phone.
However I found another issue and I will put it here to help others.
The code at the android training site:
[Monitor Changes in Charging State](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html#CurrentLevel)

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    int status = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
    boolean isCharging = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING ||
                        status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL;

    int chargePlug = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);
    boolean usbCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB;
    boolean acCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC;
}
```

`isCharging` is always `false` even when device is plugged in. This can be fixed by the following code:

```
    if(intent.getAction() == Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "isCharging: " + true, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else if(intent.getAction() == Intent.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED){
        Toast.makeText(context, "isCharging: " + false, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```