# BroadcastReceiver to execute something on Intent.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, shutdown

I am trying to execute the shutdown of the device when the USB is get unplugged. To do this, I am using a BroadcastReceiver as Google says, but it is not working, when the USB is plugged it works, but it doesn't work when it is unplugged.

This is my BroadcastReceiver class:

```
public class PowerDetector extends BroadcastReceiver{
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    //1. Detect if the power is connected or disconnected
    String action = intent.getAction();

    if(action.equals(Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED))
    {
        // Do something when power connected
        Toast.makeText(context, "CONNECT", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else if(action.equals(Intent.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED))
    {
        // Do something when power disconnected
        Toast.makeText(context, "Disconnected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        SplashScreen.SafeDisconnection();
    }
}
```

}

As I understand with Android documentation, only with this class it works. But later I saw that you can call a receiver from a external class like this:

```
private void initPowerOff(){
    PowerDetector powerDetector = new PowerDetector();

    IntentFilter powerDisconnectedFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED);
    registerReceiver(powerDetector, powerDisconnectedFilter);
}
```

But it still not working. It seem easy in the documentation... so I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

This is how I declared the Receiver in the manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".Utils.PowerDetector">
     <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED" />
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED" />
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN" />
     </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I am going to update the post to show you this.

Comment: The second type is not a call, it is [registering](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts#context-registered-receivers) in the context.

If you register them as Context-registered receivers, when your application is not working, it will not be notified.

Comment: No, I haven't, only the "CONNECT" message is showed.

Comment: Done, but  it still not working, and I changed the initPowerOff method: BroadcastReceiver br = new PowerDetector();

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);
        this.registerReceiver(br, filter);

Comment: register only at manifest. When your application is closed, you cannot get the intent if they are not registered in the Manifest. You have utils sub-package?

Comment: Sorry, the intent action is: Intent.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED. The log i wrote only works when I plug th USB.

Comment: But I have the receiver in the manifest. And the receiver class is in a package called Utils.

Comment: Ok i'll remove it and try.

Comment: Ok, I have removed the initPowerOff method and tried but it didn't work.

Comment: try battery monitor. https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring#java

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37871318/android-event-action-power-connected-and-action-power-disconnected-not-sent-to) might help